# NumberFormatException pointing to a double input on an integer

Tags: java

I am currently running a ticket issuing program which I believed was complete, however after I have created a few ticket bookings and written them to a text file, I try to run after a second or third input and it gives me this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "59.75"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at TicketBoxProject.TicketBoxMain.main(TicketBoxMain.java:94)
```

```
try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("BookingsList.txt"));
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("BookingsList.txt");
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String str;
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Bookings booking = new Bookings(); // single job of class
                                                // JobList
            booking.setFName(str);
            str = br.readLine();
            booking.setSName(str);
            str = br.readLine();
            booking.setHouseNo(str);
            str = br.readLine();
            booking.setStreet(str);
            str = br.readLine();
            booking.setTown(str);
            str = br.readLine();
            booking.setPostCode(str);
            str = br.readLine();
            booking.setEmail(str);
            str = br.readLine();
            booking.setCardType(str);
            str = br.readLine();
            booking.setCardNumber(Long.parseLong(str));
            str = br.readLine();
            booking.setCardExpiryDate(str);
            str = br.readLine();
            booking.setCardSecurityNo(Integer.parseInt(str));
            str = br.readLine();
            booking.setTicketsReqd(Integer.parseInt(str));
            str = br.readLine();
            booking.setTotal(Double.parseDouble(str));
            str = br.readLine();
            booking.setRefNo(Integer.parseInt(str));
            str = br.readLine();
            booking.setDate(str);
            str = br.readLine();
            booking.setArtist(str);
            str = br.readLine();
            booking.setVenue(str);
            str = br.readLine();
            booking.setCity(str);
            str = br.readLine();

            bookings.add(booking); // add to arraylist
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    br.close();
```

`java:94` points to the `setTicketsReqd` line, however the `"59.75"` should refer to the `setTotal` line below this, as you can see from the code, I have ensured the TicketsReqd is an integer and the Total is a Double. If anyone knows a quick fix apart from deleting the file from the textfile I would appreciate it as I can't understand why the error message is telling me there is a fault from the input "59.75"(which is the total from a previous written-to-textfile booking) and then points to a different line of code.

Comment: Well, "59.75" is obviously not an integer, right?  So you're trying to read an int and the input is a double, that's the issue.

Comment: Apparently, there is one field/line missing in the input file.

Comment: you could create a method like readLineAndForceInteger() which catches the FormatException and tries to force conversion to an Integer (by simply removing everything from the . onwards). If this fits the data you have

Comment: one more suggestion: perhaps you should change your program to use something more structured like a json, xml or even csv file. That would enable you to grasp which information you try to read is missing and continue gracefully.

Comment: I have checked all the field/line in case of a missing one, but I wll check again, cant see why there would be if I was able to run it before writing to textfile, but thanks Glorfindel

Comment: thanks Marged I will look into the force conversion to see if its possible, I am a bit new to all this and only know how to write to a textfile but I will have a look at how to use one of the other options, I hadnt even considered that at all.

Comment: will add another comment if i can resolve this, now i have a few options to play with, thanks all

Answer (score 1):

In your code, I count `19` calls to the `readLine()` method, both as part of the `while` loop condition and the body of the loop.  But I see only 18 `setXyz` methods called on the `Bookings` instance.

The last `readLine()` call in the loop is ignored; it's replaced by the call to `readLine()` in the condition of the `while` loop.  It will read in the first line in the next entry and ignore it.  Then the first `readLine` call will read in what was meant to be the second line in the booking.  This likely is causing an "off by one" error, so that `59.75` is now being read in by the line that calls `Integer.parseInt`.

Remove that last `readLine()` call.

Comment: Sometimes I just have to look at myself in a mirror and start tutting, I should have spotted this, thank you very much rgettman for spotting that, I was wondering why it worked then it didnt and now it seems so obvious as I had to earlier re-order the list, doh!  thanks again, hope this helps others that may come across this as I suppose it could easily be done.